# JS - Como funciona Drag & Drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer drag and drop con js he tratado de hacerlo funcionar pero no me funciona para nada, no se si hay alguna cosa que no sepa y deba colocar para que funcione???

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Arrastrables</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
    div{
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:2px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
#cuadrado{
    left:150px;
}
#cuadrado1{
    left:500px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="scripts/arrastrar.js"></script>
    <div id="cuadrado" style="background-color: yellow" draggable="true">Arrastrame</div>
    <div id="cuadrado1">Meta!!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
document.getElementById('cuadrado').addEventListener('dragleave', function () {
  this.opacity = "0.5";
});
document.getElementById('cuadrado2').addEventListener('dragover', function () {
  this.style.background = 'red';
});
document.getElementById('cuadrado2').addEventListener('dragstop', function () {

  this.innerHTML = '¡¡¡Acierto!!!';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con:

- En el evento `dragstart` guardas ID del elemento que estás arrastrando usando [`dataTransferSetData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData)
- En el elemento que permite soltar asignas el evento `dragover` y solo evitas que el cursor aparezca como "No permitido"
- En el elemento que permite soltar asignas el evento `drop` para añadir ahí el elemento arrastrado o realizar los cambios necesarios en estilos.

```js
document.getElementById('capa1').addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
  // Guardar información del elemento arrastrado
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
  this.style.opacity = "0.5";
});
document.getElementById('capa2').addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
  // Evitar que el cursor aparezca como "No permitido"
  e.preventDefault();
  this.style.background = 'red';
});
document.getElementById('capa2').addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
  // Detener evento, podría recargar la página
  e.preventDefault();
  this.style.background = 'yellow';
  this.innerHTML = '¡¡¡Lo has logrado!!!';
  // Obtener información del elemento arrastrado
  let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  // Agregar a contenedor
  // e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  // En lugar de agregar, solo cambiar visibilidad
  // Es mejor usar display para evitar cambios en el cursor
  document.getElementById(data).style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#capa1, #capa2 {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:1em;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
#capa1{
    left:50px;
    cursor:move;
}
#capa2{
    left:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Arrastrables</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="capa1" style="background-color: yellow" draggable="true">Arrastrame</div>
    <div id="capa2">Meta!!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo asegúrate de cargar el archivo del script hasta abajo, antes de `</body>` para que el DOM ya esté cargado.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para usar posición fija. Si no te funciona, por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actual.

Comment: Recuerda siempre revisar la consola del navegador, ahí podrás ver si hay algún error.